# EF Core 7 (Entity Framework) Multiple relationships to same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have 2 classes. A Company Class and an Item class.

An Item has 2 Companies assigned to it in different roles.

A company has a list of all items it's been assigned to, which is used to determine what users assigned to the company can see.

```
public class ServiceCompany
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
}

public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public Guid? DistributionCompanyId { get; set; }
    public ServiceCompany? DistributionCompany { get; set; }
    public Guid? ManufacturingCompanyId { get; set; }
    public ServiceCompany? ManufacturingCompany { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to set multiple relationships between `Item` and `ServiceCompany`:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Item> builder)
{
    builder.HasOne(x => x.DistributionCompany)
        .WithMany(x => x.Items)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.DistributionCompanyId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Items_Companies_DistributionCompanyId");

    builder.HasOne(x => x.ManufacturingCompany)
        .WithMany(x => x.Items)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ManufacturingCompanyId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Items_Companies_ManufacturingCompanyId");
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot create a relationship between 'ServiceCompany.Items' and 'Item.ManufacturingCompany' because a relationship already exists between 'ServiceCompany.Items' and 'Item.DistributionCompany'. Navigations can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'Item.ManufacturingCompany' first in 'OnModelCreating'.

All the searching I've found say to add another type instead of company, but that can't work in this case because they both need to be the same type. and I can't add a 2nd collection on the Item side because we use the Items collection for security to determine who can view them.

Has anyone worked out a way to use multiple relationships in this manner?

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can bring.

Answer (score 1):

You need two Lists of Items on the `ServiceCompany` type because these are two different relationships in your database.

```
public class ServiceCompany
{
    ...
    public List<Item> ManufacturingItems { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
    public List<Item> DistributionItems { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Item> builder)
{
    builder.HasOne(x => x.DistributionCompany)
        .WithMany(x => x.DistributionItems)
        ...;

    builder.HasOne(x => x.ManufacturingCompany)
        .WithMany(x => x.ManufacturingItems)
        ...;
}
```